# Combine two input audio/video in Nginx RTMP

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, m3u8

I'm trying to do a Web TV for my Radio but i'm stucked into this problem.

I'm trying to put a video loop (mp4) and trying to add into that loop the audio source of my radio who stream in m3u8 via Shoutcast.

Is possible to do this? I try to search everything on internet without any particular result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-stream_loop`:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -i rtmp:// -map 0:v -map 1:a output
```

`-re` will play `input.mp4` at realtime for streaming instead of as fast as possible.

Make sure you use FFmpeg 4.0 or newer or it will not work.

Comment: I try with this command with an output.m3u8 but when video finish, ffmpeg continue working but m3u8 stops refresh.

Comment: I fixed because i see stream_loop works only on FFMPEG 4.x and not older than 4.x. Can you edit your reply with about the version not older than 4.x? I will put as correct !